# encrypt password column using Sequelize and mysql

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize at first time and have a question about encrypt user password.

I want use the function AES_ENCRYPT to encrypt a string text.
My question is, how can I call that function on sequelize??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is `bcrypt` package and hook `beforeCreate` ,

What it will do is before inserting entry to DB will check passowrd field and encrypt is before insert into DB

Here you go **(Snippet for password encrypt)** :

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var User = db.sequelize.define( 'user' , {
    ...
    password : {
        type : db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    ...
},
{
    hooks : {
        beforeCreate : (user , options) => {
            {
                user.password = user.password && user.password != "" ? bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, 10) : "";
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: There is not another way without external packages?

Comment: @Raugaral , this packages is most popular for encryption, so dont worry about it , you wont regret on this.

Comment: Writing your own encryption is a bad idea, encryption is incredibly sophisticated and it's easy to make costly mistakes.  bcrypt is a popular library so it's secure and works well!

Comment: You can't decrypt if you have encrypted with bcrypt. @KieranQuinn

Comment: Correct, this is the reason I couldn't use any form of NodeJs encryption

Comment: @KieranQuinn , you can use crypto js and use other encryption method so that you can decrypt it back , like AES. https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js

Answer (score 3):

You nedd bcrypt and hooks : beforeCreate and beforeUpdate.

```
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
...
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
    }
...
});

function generateHash(user) {
    if (user === null) {
        throw new Error('No found employee');
    }
    else if (!user.changed('password')) return user.password;
    else {
        let salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync();
        return user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, salt);
    }
}

User.beforeCreate(generateHash);

User.beforeUpdate(generateHash);
```